# Netsuite how to edit list of terms under the billing sub-tab of a PO

Tags: netsuite

I've been searching high and low for this, but cannot seem to find it anywhere in Netsuite or howto on the web.  On a purchase order, under the billing sub-tab, there is a drop down box for terms.  Clicking on the name of the box tells you that if you want to add a new term, go to Setup > Accounting > Accounting Lists > New > Terms.  Problem is, I want to delete a term that we added in there years ago.  Does anyone know how to get to this list so that it can be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Setup>Accounting>Accounting Lists. Then open the filters area and select Terms. This is assuming you have Administrator privileges. I do not recall off the top of my head what permission would be needed specifically if you are not an Admin for the account.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked all over for that.  ;)  I checked the accepted answer, but Stack won't show my upvote because my rep is too low.